# Are those dyadic intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

I see that those are not Dyadic intervals because the length of the dyadic interval must be $2^{-j}$, am I right? or can the length of the dyadic interval be different from this? 
$$I_{R} = [(2k+1)2^{-j-1},(k+1)2^{-j}[, I_{L} = [k 2^{-j},(2k+1)2^{-j-1}[$$

If they are Dyadic intervals what are their lengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(k+1)2^{-j}-(2k+1)2^{-j-1}=2^{-j-1}$$ and

$$(2k+1)2^{-j-1}-k2^{-j}=2^{-j-1},$$

so these are indeed dyadic intervals.

Comment: So the length of the Dyadic interval not necessarily $2^{-j}$

Comment: @weakmathematician: don't take the expression $2^{-j}$ verbatim. What matters is that every interval is the half of its parent.